# C - request for member in something not a structure or union

Tags: c

Long story short I am trying to access a function inside one of my structures. Below is a simplified verson of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    void *data;
} A_t;

typedef struct
{
    void (*function)(void);
} B_t;

void myfunction(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello world.\n");
}

int main(int p_argc, char *p_argv[])
{
    A_t A;
    B_t B;

    B.function = myfunction;
    A.data = &B;
    A.data.function();

    return 0;
}
```

When trying to compile this code I get:

```
main.c:24:11: error: request for member ‘function’ in something not a structure or union
 A.data.function();
```

Could somebody explain me how to properly access this function via the A-structure?

Thanks

Comment: `a.data` is a **pointer**, so you can't just use `.` (`->` would be appropriate). And then, `a.data` has type `void *`, you can't ever dereference that!

Comment: @FelixPalmen true about the arrow. I didn't pay attention to that when writing this simplified code snippet. But doing A.data->function, doesn't work. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: As I said, `a.data` is a pointer **to `void`**. That's an unknown/generic pointer. You can't dereference it. I see no reason why you use `void *` in the first place, just use the correct type.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A.data is of type `void*`. If you want to use it as B_t object, you need to tell the compiler that it's a B_t object (he's just a child, not very smart). You need to cast it if you want to use as B_t object, like `((B_t*)A.data)->function()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I need this because I may need to point to any type of structure. Depending on the type of structure you have different functions.

Comment: then you need to remember that type in another way (e.g. a custom defined enum) and cast as appropriate before dereferencing. C doesn't have **any** type information in the resulting program, so there's really no way to know what to do with a `void *`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Long story short, it's about encapsulation. B can be "encapsulated" in any type of structure: A_t, C_t, ... I need to access the parent

Comment: @KamilCuk segmentation fault: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qtfvSMW4pK/

Comment: @FelixPalmen Casting doesn't seem to work, it gives a segmentation fault for some reason. (cf. above)

Comment: Casting does not replace a missing initialization.`B.function` is not initialized.

Comment: @Gerhardh `B.function = myfunction;` <- I'd say it is ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen The version with cast is in the pastebin link. Not the code in the question body. The line you quote was removed there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

data is of type void *, you need to type cast before de-referencing.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    void *data;
} A_t;

typedef struct
{
    void (*function)(void);
} B_t;

void myfunction(void)
{
    fprintf(stdout, "Hello world.\n");
}

int main(int p_argc, char *p_argv[])
{
    A_t A;
    B_t B;

    B.function = myfunction;
    A.data = &B;
    ((B_t*)(A.data))->function();

    return 0;
}
```